# Joomla Load Module in Featured Article

Tags: joomla2.5, article, loadmodule

What I use: 
   - Joomla 2.5 
   - gantry framework

Need:
**I must place in my homepage a slideshow module inside the**  *mainbody* **as a** *featured article*.

What I did:
Installed a slideshow module and placed temporary inside gantry's maintop-a position to see if it worked (it did), then moved in a non-previously-exsisting 'slideshow' position.

Created a new article, with this content: `{loadposition slideshow}` and set it to featured state.

Result: 
the article was published correctly but the introtext char limit trimmed the actual module code to 100 chars making it useless.

What I already tried to fix the issue:

- Modified my slideshow article from database adding the loadmodule code in the fulltext field (which was originally empty), 
  then modified `components/com_content/view/featured/tmpl/default_item.php` replacing `echo $this->item->introtext;`  with an `if` to identify my slideshow article id then query the database to find the fulltext field and echo it. this thingy works but the loadmodule function isn't, so it's displayed as simple HTML. I deduce that introtext is treated differently than fulltext since what's inside the brackets is interpreted as code only when echoed as introtext, and I miss that layer.
- Modified `modules/mod_articles_category/helper.php` to break the 100 introtext_limit, sadly finding that's not called for my featured articles (added `dump($item, 'some name')` which returns only the articles that are inside my news sidebar, even if all my featured articles including slideshow are categorized)
- tried a million different combinations of the above (i.e.:`{loadmodule slideshow}`
  `{module [myslideshow_article_id]}` <- a module loader plugin i tried, ...) which are too long to put here.
- Searched the whole project folder for files containing 'introtext' inside their code, finding alot, but nothing that actually trims it (except helper.php of course)
- Searched the Joomla API
- Googled for everything that came into my mind finding no working solutions.
- Came Here :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show a module inside an artice, you can use an component to show them there.
In my experience, this works on normal and featured articles, so this might work for you:
http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/modulesanywhere

I hope this was helpfull, since this is my first answer here.
Kind Regards,
McBurgerKong